# Move First Word to end of String Java

Tags: java, string, filereader

move keywords flagstop, wb, nb, sb, eb from start of the names to the end of the names
of the stops when reading the file
eg “WB HASTINGS ST FS HOLDOM AVE” becomes “HASTINGS ST FS HOLDOM AVE WB”.

So far I have gotten the code to read in the file as shown below, but im unsure how to move keyword of this string in array to end of string given the criteria shown above.
I need to be able to move first word in stops[2] if it is any of the above postcodes. Is there a way in JAVA to do this? Im thinking I need to make separate a function (moveFirstToLast) and call this in the main, but im having difficulty with this.
'''

```
    String line = "";

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        BufferedReader x = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stops.txt"));
        while((line = x.readLine()) != null)
        {

            String[] stops = line.split(",");
            System.out.println("Stop name:" + stops[2]);
    
        }
    }
```

'''

Comment: Depending on how complex this is going to need to be you might want to have a look at java RegEx. This would let you pick out specific patterns in the string and move them wherever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex replacement:

```java
String input = "WB HASTINGS ST FS HOLDOM AVE";
String output = input.replaceAll("(\\S+) (.*)$", "$2 $1");
System.out.println(output);  // HASTINGS ST FS HOLDOM AVE WB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String#split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to separate the first word from the rest of the string.

```java
public moveFirstToLast(String stopName){
  String [] temp = stopName.split(" ", 2);
  return temp[1] + " " + temp[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Sample_Two {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "";

        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            BufferedReader x = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stops.txt"));
            while ((line = x.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Actual line===>" + line);
                var arr = line.split("\\s");
                if (arr != null && arr.length > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Updated line===>" + line.substring(line.indexOf(" ")) +" "+ arr[0]);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can try above code.
Why you are splitting through comma **`","`**.

**`You need to split through space.`**

This will help you.